# Shift row selection in ag-grid in Internet Explorer selects additional text

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, ag-grid

I have tried the following example of ag-grid implementation:
[Example - Multiple Row Selection](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-selection/index.php) . Particulary **Example - Multiple Row Selection**. When I select the rows with shift in Chrome-Mozilla-Opera, everything is fine, as you can see on the picture 1.

[image]

Unfortunately, I also have to support IE browser. When I do the same operation in IE, some additional text also selected: titles above and so on. Is there a way to solve this issue?

[image]

p.s. Is it better to prepare a plunkr for this example or the example from ag-grid websites are enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turn off user selection for you page, put this css onto the body:
body {
    user-select: none;
}

the grid does this for the grid, but doesn't try and do it for the rest of your app (it shouldn't). the problem is how IE is understanding the shift-click, so i don't think it's a grid issue, best is to work around it. it's pretty standard to turn off user-select on single page web-apps when they are detailed applications (which i'm guessing yours is, if you are using ag-Grid).

Comment: It works. I need only to add body `{ -ms-user-select: none }` to apply this rule for Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, for selecting rows (not cells!) I prefer a checkbox at the beginning of the row. And it might solve your problem with IE.

Use the attribute **checkboxSelection** on the column definition, eg:

```
{headerName: "Athlete", field: "athlete",  checkboxSelection: true},
```

If you want to enforce selecting rows by checkboxes, you can set the property **suppressRowClickSelection** in the gridOptions to **true**.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the checkbox does solve the problem, but, unfortunately, I can't use it in my project. I found a temporary solution and posted it below.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the solution is to use:

`$window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();`

in

```
onRowSelected
```

Listener. So, every time the rows selection is changed, the selection of other elements in IE will be removed. Not a good solution, but better that nothing.
[Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/removeAllRanges)

Comment: Is this happening instantaneously for you? When I try this solution, I still see the selection elsewhere on screen flash before being removed, and it seems a bit jarring.

Comment: @dsh Unfortunately, not instantaneously. The wrong selected areas appears for some short period of time (100-300ms) and then disappears. Currently, I have not found any other solution: either use checkboxes as Alexander Zbinden proposed above or this "hack".